# OleInitialize fails when Common Lanuage Runtime is enabled?

Tags: c++, clr, wxwidgets

I am working on a wxWidgets console application that I want to call into = a C# DLL from, via the CLR.  Unfortunately, the application hiccups in the wxWidgets application initialization code because OleInitialize is failing.  The error I'm seeing is a pop-up simply stating "Cannot initialize OLE."

It seems that this problem is usually avoided by setting the apartment style for threads by applying a directive to the application's entry point but I'm really struggling with what entry point I'm looking for.  My C# code is a DLL: there's no specific entry point.  The code compiled with /CLR exists in a .lib which is linked into my wxWidgets application.  wxWidgets actually defines the WinMain in their code, and allows me to override behaviors via implementing wxApp.

Other suggestions include disabling OLE support in wxWidgets but In my release, 2.8.6, setting `wxUSE_OLE, wxUSE_CLIPBOARD, wxUSE_DATAOBJ, wxUSE_DRAG_AND_DROP` to 0 creates unresolved externals while compiling wxWidgets.

Has enjoy encountered this before and found an effective work around?  Can anyone provide any clarification on what entry point I need to be modifying?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in my question, this is a problem involving the thread style settings between the C++ application and the CLR defaults.  This was apparently a bug, once upon a time, and Microsoft has released a fix:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s6bz81ya.aspx

Recompiling the executable the uses the CLR-enabled .lib with /CLRTHREADATTRIBUTE:STA was sufficient to eliminate the errors I was seeing.